# Spring + restful + cors + not func

Tags: spring, rest, cors

I am having a problem in my restful service with spring. Even after enabling CORS, I can not connect to my angular application.

```
@CrossOrigin
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService service; 

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/lista_todos_usuarios", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Usuario>> buscaTodosUsuarios() {
        Collection<Usuario> usuarios = service.buscaTodosUsuarios();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usuarios, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Comment: The reference documentation states that I should just annotate the controller with @CrossOrigin so that access is possible from any source. However, I remain unrelated to my endpoit / controller.

Comment: Your class is not marked as `@RestController` so it won't handle REST requests

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, sometimes we miss out on obvious things. Hehehe

Answer (score 0):

From [**Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

In your case, I think you need indicate what origin is allowed to access the service.

In the example, the origin is `http://localhost:9000`. It should correspond to your Angular application.

> ### Enabling CORS
>
> **Controller method CORS configuration**
>
> So that the RESTful web service will include CORS access control
>   headers in its response, you just have to add a `@CrossOrigin`
>   annotation to the handler method:
>
> ```
> src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
> @GetMapping("/greeting")
> public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
>     System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
>     return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple workaround I could recommend to install CORS extension plugin for Chrome and use it during initial development stages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global configuration, you may override method *addCorsMappings* of **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** in your web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class DispatcherContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nikolay, sometimes we miss out on obvious things. Hehehe

in fact, I forgot to annotate the class with @RestController.